# Why does pnorm() change the correlation in my multivariate normal sample?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, simulation, copula, eigenvalues

I came across 2 problems that puzzle me while simulating variables for a Monte Carlo simulation, using the rnormalcopula command from the rCopula example. The first one is the one from the title, the second one only a related self-study question. Required packages are MASS, copula and mvtnorm. I first noticed the correlations in samples created with `copula` seemed to be slightly off, as shown by this quick example:

```
copN.cor <- replicate(5000, {
copN <- normalCopula(0.9)
rv <- rCopula(10000, copN)
cor(rv[,1],rv[,2], method="pearson")
})
hist(copN.cor)
```

[image: *this text is supposed to be a picture of the histogram*]

The expected correlations are clearly biased and seem to fall between 0.891 and 0.893 instead of 0.9.

So I had a look into rCopula, turns out it uses pnorm and rmvnorm from the package mvtnorm with *method = "eigen"* (see [here](https://github.com/cran/copula/blob/master/R/normalCopula.R)):

```
rnormalCopula <- function(n, copula)
pnorm(rmvnorm(n, sigma = getSigma(copula)))
```

If I replicate the above code leaving out pnorm(), I get unbiased samples with expected Correlation of 0.9:

```
copN.mvtn <- replicate(5000, {
  rv <- pnorm(rmvnorm(n = 1000, mean = rep(0,2),sigma = sigma, method="eigen"))
  cor(rv[,1],rv[,2],method="pearson")
})
hist(copN.mvtn)
```

[image: *this text is supposed to be a picture of the histogram*]

So the problem is with pnorm(). In my understanding, pnorm *should* return an unbiased sample - my first question is therefore, why doesn't it?

The second question came up when I was trying to figure out the problem and went through the functions of `rmvnorm` from package mvtnorm and `mvrnorm` from MASS, which seem to be using different functions. I don't understand what the mvtnorm package is doing.

```
R <- if (method == "eigen") {
ev <- eigen(sigma, symmetric = TRUE)
t(ev$vectors %*% (t(ev$vectors) * sqrt(pmax(ev$values, 0))))
}

retval <- matrix(rnorm(n * ncol(sigma)), nrow = n, byrow = !pre0.9_9994) %*% R
retval <- sweep(retval, 2, mean, "+")
```

That seems to be a multidimensional normal sample multiplied with a matrix R. With $z$ as the uncorrelated normal sample matrix, $*$ denoting element-wise multiplication, and $\lambda$ as the vector containing the eigenvalues (as opposed to $\Lambda$, which is the diagonal matrix with eigenvalues), this gives us:

$$ z(U(U^T * \lambda^\frac{1}{2}))^T $$

Afterwards the means are applied.

mvrnorm from MASS, on the other hand, uses this code:

```
eS <- eigen(Sigma, symmetric = TRUE)
ev <- eS$values
X <- matrix(rnorm(p * n), n)
X <- drop(mu) + eS$vectors %*% diag(sqrt(pmax(ev, 0)), p) %*% 
   t(X)
```

Which I would translate to

$$ \mu *U \Lambda^\frac{1}{2} z^T $$

So MASS is a pretty straightforward implementation of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution).

But what is mvtnorm doing? I don't understand the purpose of multiplying $(U^T * \lambda^\frac{1}{2})$, as opposed to directly using $\Lambda^\frac{1}{2}$.

Thanks for any help!

Here is a minimum working example in R for the first question. It shows the different correlations after using pnorm and the bias over repetitions:

```
library(mvtnorm)

n = 1000
sigma = matrix(c(1,0.6,0.7,0.6,1,0.55,0.7,0.55,1),nrow=3)
mean = rep(0,nrow(sigma))
ev = eigen(sigma,symmetric=TRUE)

#### change from transformation
rv <- rmvnorm(n = 10000, mean = mean,sigma = sigma, method="eigen")
cor(rv)
cor(pnorm(rv))

#### bias visible over replications

copN.mvtn <- replicate(2000, {
    rv <- rmvnorm(n = 10000, mean = mean,sigma = sigma, method="eigen")
    cor(rv[,1],rv[,2],method="pearson")
})
hist(copN.mvtn)

copN.pnorm <- replicate(2000, {
  rv <- pnorm(rmvnorm(n = 10000, mean = mean,sigma = sigma, method="eigen"))
  cor(rv[,1],rv[,2],method="pearson")
})
hist(copN.pnorm)
```

Comment: Interesting but... attempting the direct comparison with simulations using `rmvnorm` and `mvrnorm` does not exhibit this difference. I thus suspect the copula interface may be responsible for the difference.

Comment: Wow, you're right. I spent all this time thinking it had to be `rmvnorm`, but the culprit was actually `pnorm()` and thus rCopula, and not `rmvnorm` or `mvrnorm`, which I forgot to add when I replicated the function. I will edit the question to reflect this.